# Process Builder doesn't seem to execute from Test Methods

Tags: unit-test, process-builder

I have Process Builders built on Cases which makes the following job:

- Change Owner to Queue on Create
- Change Status to 'New' on Create, to 'In Progress' on Accept, and changes parent case Status to 'Clarified' on Close.

This works perfectly well in the GUI.

When I run test methods which create and updates a Case,  I check the status change with this code :

```
    //--- Taking ownership and closing the Case
    System.RunAs( tmc.usrSocial ) {
        //--Takes ownership of the Case - 
        // PB should changes the status from 'New' to 'In Progress' when the owner changes
        cr_case.OwnerId = tmc.usrSocial.Id;   
        update cr_case;
    }

    // Checks Case Status
    System.AssertEquals('In Progress', cr_case.Status );
    // Fails: cr_case.status still has the value 'New'
```

Even when executing System.asserEquals() after Test.stopTest() the test fails.

What am I missing ?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After your `update cr_case;` statement, do a SOQL query for the same case. You are calling `assertEquals()` on the Case you currently have in memory, so you need to get the "updated" version from the database first.

Comment: Bon sang !!! I didn't think of that. You're right : 1 record but 2 storages because of 2 distinct processes. Thank you so much